# Avoid redundancy in this list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

How can I avoid querying the set object `sol` unnecessarily in this list comprehension? Currently, I query it twice for each object, once in the ternary and once in the predicate. However, I cannot think of a more elegant solution. Is there one?

```
dnf = (
    (
        (
            d if p[i,d,True] in sol
            else
            -d if p[i,d,False] in sol
        )
        for d in range(N)
        if p[i,d,True] in sol or p[i,d,False] in sol
    )
    for i in range(M)
)
```

Comment: Can you show us sol?

Comment: @MishaVacic `sol` is an arbitrary set of integers. `p` is an arbitrary integer-valued dictionary.

Comment: Have you tried to unwind your generator and look at it that way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can identify that case with `None` and filter it out:

```
dnf = (
    (
        x for x in (
            d if p[i,d,True] in sol else
            -d if p[i,d,False] in sol else None
            for d in range(N)
        )
        if x is not None
    )
    for i in range(M)
)
```

Or chain iterables in one of various ways:

```
dnf = (
    (
        x
        for d in range(N)
        for x in (
            (d,) if p[i,d,True] in sol else
            (-d,) if p[i,d,False] in sol else ()
        )
    )
    for i in range(M)
)
```

But have you considered a function instead?

```
def get_dnf(N, p, sol, i):
    for d in range(N):
        if p[i,d,True] in sol:
            yield d
        elif p[i,d,False] in sol:
            yield -d


dnf = (get_dnf(N, p, sol, i) for i in range(M))
```

Comment: I vote for the generator function: why try to torture yourself figuring out how to make a generator expression/comprehension??